# How to find the mean of the outlier values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('aaaabbbbab'),
                   'val':[1,3,3,2,5,6,6,2,10,12],
                   'id':[1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,12,14],
                   })
```

I would like to get the mean of the outlier values for each group (a and b). please help.

I am able to find the number of outliers record, total grp count, grp mean from the above df using the below code

```
def get_num_outliers (column):

     q1 = np.percentile(column, 25)

     q3 = np.percentile(column, 75)

     return sum((column<q1) | (column>q3))

df.groupby('group').agg([get_num_outliers,'count','mean'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking a bit your function:

```
def get_mean_outliers (column):
     q1 = np.percentile(column, 25)
     q3 = np.percentile(column, 75)
     return column[(column<q1) | (column>q3)].mean()

df.groupby('group').agg([get_num_outliers,'count','mean', get_mean_outliers])
```

Output:

```
                   val                                            id                             
      get_num_outliers count mean get_mean_outliers get_num_outliers count mean get_mean_outliers
group                                                                                            
a                    2     5  3.8               5.5                1     5  3.6              12.0
b                    2     5  6.2               7.0                2     5  5.0               8.0
```